# SQL Query to get last 4 Quarters with last 2 digit of Year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to get the last 4 records from a table and it has records with column value like '19Q1','18Q4'.

using below query I can get last 4 quarters but is there any simplest form of this query.

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER,  CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,0,GETDATE())), 0) )) as VARCHAR) + 'Q' + CAST(Right(Cast(Year(DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,0,GETDATE())), 0) ) As varchar(4)),2) as VARCHAR) as Period
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER,  CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-1,GETDATE())), 0) )) as VARCHAR) + 'Q' + CAST(Right(Cast(Year(DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-1,GETDATE())), 0) ) As varchar(4)),2) as VARCHAR) as Period
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER,  CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-2,GETDATE())), 0) )) as VARCHAR) + 'Q' + CAST(Right(Cast(Year(DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-2,GETDATE())), 0) ) As varchar(4)),2) as VARCHAR) as Period
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER,  CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-3,GETDATE())), 0) )) as VARCHAR) + 'Q' + CAST(Right(Cast(Year(DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,DATEADD(q,-3,GETDATE())), 0) ) As varchar(4)),2) as VARCHAR) as Period
```

**O/P:**

```
1Q19
4Q18
3Q18
2Q18
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using 2012 (because you've tagged 3 different versions of SQL Server...) How about:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(QUARTER,Q.D),'Q',RIGHT(DATEPART(YEAR,Q.D),2))
FROM (VALUES(0),(-1),(-2),(-3)) V(i)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(QUARTER,V.i,GETDATE()))) Q(D);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST( DATEPART(q, DATEADD(q, -v.num, d.CurrentDate) ) AS VARCHAR(1)) 
+ 'Q'
+ RIGHT( CAST( DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(q, -v.num, d.CurrentDate)) AS VARCHAR(4) ), 2 )
FROM ( VALUES ( GETDATE() ) ) d(CurrentDate)
    CROSS JOIN ( VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3) ) v(num)
ORDER BY DATEADD(q, -v.num, d.CurrentDate) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Gets Current Quarter start date going back 5 quarters plus Qx - format year

```
--QCurrent
select DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 0, 0) as QCurrentStartDate, 
'Q' + cast(datepart(quarter,( DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 0, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) + ' - ' 
+ cast(datepart(year, (DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 0, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) as QLast

--LastQuarter
select DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) as LastQuarterStartDate, 
'Q' + cast(datepart(quarter,( DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) + ' - ' 
+ cast(datepart(year, (DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) as QCurrent

--SecondQuarterBack
select DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0) as SecondQuarterStartDate, 
'Q' + cast(datepart(quarter,( DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) + ' - ' 
+ cast(datepart(year, (DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) as SecondCurrent

--ThreeQuarterBack
select DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0) as SecondQuarterStartDate, 
'Q' + cast(datepart(quarter,( DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) + ' - ' 
+ cast(datepart(year, (DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) as SecondCurrent

--FourQuarterBack
select DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 4, 0) as SecondQuarterStartDate, 
'Q' + cast(datepart(quarter,( DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 4, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) + ' - ' 
+ cast(datepart(year, (DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) -4, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) as SecondCurrent

select datepart(year, (DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) -4, 0)))

select format(getdate(), 'yy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Great earlier answer by Phil, here is an extended version with a temp table with start and end dates which you can then join on other tables to get labels and proper order:

```
--LAST FIVE QUARTERS TEMP TABLE
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#lastfivequarters') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #lastfivequarters

CREATE TABLE #lastfivequarters (QOrdinal int, QName nvarchar(10)
    , QStartDate date, QEndDate date, QLabel nvarchar(10))

INSERT INTO #lastfivequarters
SELECT * FROM (
--Current Quarter
select
1 as QOrdinal
, 'Current' as QName
, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 0, 0) as QStartDate
, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0) as QEndDate
, 'Q' + cast(datepart(quarter,( DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 0, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) + ' - ' 
+ cast(datepart(year, (DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 0, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) as QLabel
UNION
--Last Quarter
select 
2 as QOrdinal
, 'Last' as QName
, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) as QStartDate
, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 0, 0) as QEndDate
, 'Q' + cast(datepart(quarter,( DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) + ' - ' 
+ cast(datepart(year, (DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) as QLabel
UNION
--Two Quarters Back
select 
3 as QOrdinal
, 'Second' as QName
, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0) as QStartDate
, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) as QEndDate 
, 'Q' + cast(datepart(quarter,( DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) + ' - ' 
+ cast(datepart(year, (DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) as QLabel
UNION
--Three Quarters Back
select 
4 as QOrdinal
, 'Third' as QName
, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0) as QStartDate
, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0) as QEndDate
, 'Q' + cast(datepart(quarter,( DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) + ' - ' 
+ cast(datepart(year, (DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) as QLabel
UNION
--Four Quarters Back
select 
5 as QOrdinal
, 'Fourth' as QName
, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 4, 0) as QStartDate 
, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0) as QEndDate
, 'Q' + cast(datepart(quarter,( DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 4, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) + ' - ' 
+ cast(datepart(year, (DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) -4, 0))) as nvarchar(6)) as QLabel
) q

SELECT * FROM #lastfivequarters
DROP TABLE #lastfivequarters
```